# innerjoin or another way to combine data

Tags: mysql, datatable, inner-join

Out of a database I am trying to combine two tables into one search query.

Table1: faq

```
| faq_id | title | status | url_key |
| ------ | ----- | ------ | ------- |
|   1    | Test  |   1    | go.html |
```

Table2: faq_value

```
| faq_value_id | faq_id | attribute  | value          |
| ------------ | ------ | ---------  | -------        |
|      1       |    1   |  metakey   | testing        |
|      2       |    1   |  metadesc  | this is a test |
|      3       |    1   | meta_image | test.jpg        |
```

Now my desired query result would look like this:

```
| faq_id | title | status | metadesc  | metakey | meta_image | url_key |
| ------ | ----- | ------ | --------  | ------- | ---------- | ------- |
|   1    | Test  |   1    | this is a | testing | test.jpg   | go.html |
```

My attempt so far has failed:

```
SELECT 
faq.faq_id,faq.title,status,
(SELECT faq_value.value AS metadesc WHERE faq_value.attribute_code = 'metadesc'),
(SELECT faq_value.value AS metakey WHERE faq_value.attribute_code = 'metakey'),
(SELECT faq_value.value AS meta_image FROM faq_value WHERE faq_value.attribute_code = 'meta_image')
faq.url_key,
FROM faq
INNER JOIN faq_value ON faq_value.faq_id = faq.faq_id
```

I am sure I am just overlooking something silly, but just cannot spot is. This one kicks a SQL error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE faq_value.attribute_code = 'metadesc'), (SELECT faq_value.value AS metakey' at line 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 3 inner join on the faq_value table

```
   SELECT 
    faq.faq_id
  , faq.title
  , faq.status
  , b.value as metadesc
  , c.value as metakey
  , d.value as metakey
  , faq.url
from faq
INNER JOIN faq_value as b on  b.faq_id = faq.faq_id and b.attribute_code = 'metadesc'
INNER JOIN faq_value as c on  c.faq_id = faq.faq_id and c.attribute_code = 'metakey'
INNER JOIN faq_value as d on  d.faq_id = faq.faq_id and d.attribute_code = 'meta_image'
```

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c615f/4

```
SELECT 
    faq.faq_id
  , faq.title
  , faq.status
  , fv.metadesc
  , fv.metakey
  , fv.metakey
  , faq.url_key
FROM faq
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT 
    faq_id,
    MAX(IF(attribute = 'metadesc',value,null)) metadesc,
    MAX(IF(attribute = 'metakey',value,null)) metakey,
    MAX(IF(attribute = 'meta_image', value, null)) meta_image 
 FROM faq_value
 GROUP BY faq_id) fv
ON  fv.faq_id = faq.faq_id
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it is by pivoting based on the Attribute Column

Example using a dummy table constructed using UNION ALL (Aliased as A ... this will be your faq_value table):

```
SELECT FAQ_ID,
MAX( CASE WHEN Attribute = 'MetaKey' THEN Attribute ELSE '' END) As MetaKey ,
MAX( CASE WHEN Attribute = 'MetaDesc' THEN Attribute ELSE '' END) As MetaDesc  ,
MAX( CASE WHEN Attribute = 'meta_image' THEN Attribute ELSE '' END) As metaimage 

FROM 
( 

Select 'MetaKey' as Attribute  , 1 as FAQ_ID UNION ALL
Select 'MetaDEsc' as Attribute , 1 as FAQ_ID UNION ALL
Select 'meta_image' as Attribute , 1 as FAQ_ID 

) A 

GROUP BY FAQ_ID
```

Now all you need to do is join with FAQ table to get the other columns